# HTML:Margin auto not working with nav bar

Tags: html, css, margin, nav

So here's my code:

```css
.nav-item {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-style: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-container {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-container">
  <span class="nav-item">ABOUT ME</span>
  <span class="nav-item">CONTACT ME</span>
  <span class="nav-item">PORTFOLIO</span>
</nav>
```

I want to make my navigation bar centered in the middle of the page, with `margin: auto`, but for some reason, it doesn't work. When I set `display: block`, it works, but doesn't display in a line. Could someone tell me why this is?
Thanks a ton...

Comment: I don't know about your actual code, but here, you've missed `</nav>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline elements behave just like text, so you need to put the alignment on the parent.

In your CSS, remove the `margin:0 auto;` and add `text-align: center;` on `.nav-container`:

```
.nav-item{
  display:inline;
  color:white;
  padding:30px 10px;
  font-style:bold;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  width:1000px;
}

.nav-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5v7Lppkf/

Answer (score 0):

For inline elements like this, use text-align:center on the parent element, so add to your css:

```
.nav-container { text-align:center }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following rule to your CSS:

```
.nav-container { text-align: center; }
```

This should do all the magic.